# Can I disable Firefox's click to play Java function? Even just on a specific domain?

Tags: firefox, java

So here's an article on the issue for reference: http://thenextweb.com/apps/2013/01/11/following-active-exploits-mozilla-adds-all-recent-versions-of-java-to-its-firefox-add-on-blocklist/

Basically I use Firefox for just a single work function.  The client uses a Citrix plugin to access their network and long story short is the plugin is written in Java and only seems to work for me in FF.  All is well and good until today when I go to login and I am getting Java missing errors.  Basically after I login the page I see says "loading" and in the address bar I noticed an error icon that when clicked shows:

[image: Error]

I click activate as fast as I can but there's some kind of function in place when when they figure out I don't have Java installed [or in this case just deactivated] 
 they forward me to a "please install java page" and it's a vicious circle: when I land on the loading page I click activate as fast as possible but there's no "always activate on this domain" button so it forgets and just forwards me to the "please install java" page.

Very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out there is indeed a "always allow on this site" button if you open up the activate all plugins button at the bottom of my screenshot.  In any event, extremely annoying and took me about 10 tries to get there fast enough but all is well now.